yarn publish does not work with new version of _auth (.npmrc)
We had this in .npmrc file in Home directory
_auth=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

and publishing our internal package using yarn publish worked fine. Yarn version 1.22.
But now starting from npm 8 it seems they changed the _auth to //registry.npmjs.org/:_auth (we used our local repo url instead).
So when we changed that also in .npmrc, the yarn publish stopped working.
Anyone have idea how to solve this?
